# OrderBy With ThenBy Date Ordering

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list of items that need to be ordered by date.

My first try was `transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate)` which gave me a list like so

```
Trans Date | Post Date | Name
  07/15/14   07/16/14    Thing B
  07/15/14   07/16/14    Thing A
  07/11/14   07/13/14    Thing D
  07/12/14   07/13/14    Thing C
  07/09/14   07/10/14    Thing E
```

Which is clearly wrong. I'm getting the ordering of things A through E from a internal company website and they MUST be ordered the same.

My next try was 
`transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate).ThenByDescending(t => t.TransactionDate` which helped a little:

```
Trans Date | Post Date | Name
  07/15/14   07/16/14    Thing B
  07/15/14   07/16/14    Thing A
  07/12/14   07/13/14    Thing C
  07/11/14   07/13/14    Thing D
  07/09/14   07/10/14    Thing E
```

As you can see, it fixed the ordering of C and D (Yay!). Now my only problem is things A and B. In every case like this that the transaction date and post dates are equal, these two items are switched. They should be flipped and everything will be fine.

I'm guessing the other site orders by the timestamp next, but I do not have that available. However, just switching A and B should do the trick. Does anyone have an idea of how I can get this ordering to work?

**Edit:** Thing A and Thing B are not the real names of the data, and it is not sorted by name. The end result should be

```
Trans Date | Post Date | Name
  07/15/14   07/16/14    Thing A
  07/15/14   07/16/14    Thing B
  07/12/14   07/13/14    Thing C
  07/11/14   07/13/14    Thing D
  07/09/14   07/10/14    Thing E
```

Basically, whenever the trans dates and post dates of two things are the same, I want to switch them. Is there an ordering way to do that?

Comment: Both `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` are *stable*, which implies that the order of items that you get from your company web site is not what you suggest it is.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Or that OP is getting the list from an API that does not do ordering, and wants to sort the data to match a UI that does do ordering.

Comment: "Stable sort" means that the order of equal items is preserved in the output. Another thing is that you may be truncating the time portion of the post date / transaction date).

Comment: I mentioned above that I do not have the time portion available (and that is what I think they are using). I have to match their ordering though

Comment: @Bobo Did you verify that without sorting you get the order that you expect to see?

Comment: Couldn't more than two things be same?

Comment: Do you always get the `transactions` in a consistent order before you sort them? (i.e. will you _always_ need to switch `Thing A` and `Thing B`)?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev more than two things could probably be the same, I haven't run into that case yet. In that case, the items would probably just need to be reversed again.

Comment: The order I get the transactions in is completely nuts and makes no sense. (Yay third party vendor -.-) However in every case I've seen so far (a bunch), Thing A and Thing B just are in the reverse order.

Comment: @Bobo If you do not get one of the fields you need to sort the way you need to, then you can't sort the way you need to.  You can invest all of the work you want in a hack that appears to sort things correctly right now, but it *will* break later down the line when the API starts giving you things in a different order than you expected.

Comment: I've read all the comments and it is still unclear what ordering you wish to obtain. Please edit your question to include the logic behind your ordering (e.g. order by post-date desc, and if post-date's are equal then order by trans-date desc, and if trans-date's are equal then maintain order by name)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight your mentioning the stable bit made me realize something. The UI I am checking against actually orders everything oppositely, (so the smallest post date is at the top). This means they actually aren't ordering by time, but by date with the stable piece involved. Since I am ordering in reverse, using the Reverse() call in the answer below keeps things 'stable' but reversed! Thank you for making me look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always get the transactions in an order whereby you need to switch like items you could call `Reverse` before you start sorting. As the sort is stable the new order for like items will be retained:

```
transactions.Reverse();
transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate)
            .ThenByDescending(t => t.TransactionDate);
```

Other than that it seems you'll need to get the time portion of the data back too so as to make your sorting correct.

As Bobo pointed out in the comments you could order *Ascending* and then reverse the whole result set to give the same results which is perhaps neater as it's only one line:

```
transactions.OrderBy(t => t.PostDate)
            .ThenBy(t => t.TransactionDate)
            .Reverse();
```

Comment: Well hey! It works. However I realized this is the same as .OrderBy().ThenBy().Reverse()   Do you think that one is better than the other in practice?

Comment: @bobo - Using `Reverse()` at the end will reverse the _sorted_ list which in the example in your question will give `Thing E` first. Reversing before you sort will simply change the order of identical items as they will be reversed before the sort and then left in place during the sort.

Comment: Oh I mean if I switch the Order By and Then By to not be descending. Then the reverse will cause them to be descending and switch the stable pieces as well.

Comment: @petelids Note that he used `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` (not `Descending`) when he reverses the whole result. If you completely reverse the logic, then you can `Reverse` the results. Make sure to also swap the ordering field between `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` as well.

Comment: @bobo and Yorye - my bad. You're quite right, either will work and I suspect they both perform the same. Your version is probably a little neater if I'm honest. Do you want me to update the answer to cover it?

Comment: Sure you can add that on for future use :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as adding another `OrderBy` for `Name` using [`Enumerable.ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.95).aspx)

```
transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate)
           .ThenByDescending(t => t.TransactionDate)
           .ThenBy(t=> t.Name);
```

Comment: Of course this will only work if the two names in the real data sort the way OP wants.  (The names given look like placeholder names.)

Comment: Yes, the names of the items are not really Thing A and Thing B, that was just to make it simpler to read.

Comment: @Bobo, `ThenBy` or `OrderBy` would use the natural sort order for strings. If that doesn't solve your problem, then what are the exact names ? and what should be the sort order ?

Comment: The exact names are irrelevant, it is NOT sorted by name.

Answer (score 0):

If the table has a primary key with IDENTITY, then that increments as things are created.

So you can use the PK as "original order":

```
transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate)
            .ThenByDescending(t => t.TransactionDate)
            .ThenBy(t => t.PK)
```

Comment: I have a list, not a table, so I don't have a key to use.